# How do you modify existing table columns to HIDDEN in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I believe there is a new feature where you can define columns as `HIDDEN` so that a `SELECT *` returns all except hidden columns.

Is this possible? If yes, how would you achieve it with SQL Server 2016 or SQL Azure?

Comment: no. not possible. You have to explicitly specify the column name. Anyway you should not use `SELECT *` in your query.  You are getting addional un-needed column and your query might break if the table was modified in future

Comment: `HIDDEN` refers to the `DATETIME2` columns used to record the start / end times of a record with respect to the new Temporal tables feature. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx

Comment: That feature works only with temporal tables,its good to have the option of hidden column feature

Comment: You can either select columns you are interested in / use views to mask columns (also grant permissions on views if the column security is a concern)

Comment: A bit late to the party but regarding your comment below about having to refactor your stored procedures, it should be extremely easy to just write up a dynamic stored procedure creation script to fetch all currently existing columns form the data model, except the ones you specifically don't want. Then just execute that script any time you upgrade the software / db. After that, you should never have to take another look at the process again unless you get a *real* change to the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding info from the comments into the answer..

We cant specify a column as hidden and do a select * which returns all columns except hidden like Temporal tables.Moreover this feature is applicable only for validfrom,valid to columns ,though it is nice to have such a feature.As Satya mentioned you can use views  to achieve more or less the same.

Comment: OK that's a shame. Seems like a useful feature. At the moment we have to refactor all our stored procedures every time we add a column because there is one specific column we don't want.